# Ajax json post to php for multiple return values

Tags: jquery, json, post, return-value, encode

I've been following a lot of tutorials and question from the site. 
I'm trying to get an array back from a ajax call to a php function using 'echo json_encode()'

I think my issue lies with the js code

THE JS....

```
var pid = 23;
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"../classes/ajax.php",
  data: {dv:pid},
  dataType:'json',
  success: function(data) { 
    alert(data);
    $('div.dv-panel').css('background-image', 'url(../classes/' + data.url + ')');
    $('div.dv-panel').attr('href', '/classes/' + data.url);
    $('<ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a href="#">'+ data.sbj + '</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">'+ data.cls +'</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">'+ data.typ +'</a></li>      
      <li class="active">'+ data.ttl +'</li></ol>').appendTo('div.dv-breadcrumb');
    $(data.ttl).appendTo('h2.dv-title');
    $(data.user).appendTo('div.dv-user');
  }
});
```

THE PHP...

```
 if($_POST && isset($_POST['dv'])) {
$op = new Ajax;
$response = $op->doc_view_where_id($_POST['dv']);
 }


function doc_view_where_id($pid) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM upload WHERE id = ?";
    if($try = $this->con->prepare($sql)) {
        $try->bind_param('s',$pid);
        $try->execute();
        $try->bind_result($row);
        if($try->fetch()) {
            $path = $row['path'];
            $path = str_replace('\\','/',$path);
            $path = str_replace(' ','%20',$path);
            $view = array();
            $view["url"] = $path; 
            $view["sbj"] = $row['subject'];
            $view["cls"] = $row['class'];
            $view["typ"] = $row['type'];
            $view["ttl"] = $row['title'];
            $view["user"]= $row['username'];;
            echo json_encode($view);
        }

    }
}
```

i use that same php code for getting single values back with ajax just fine, and I thought using json would go the same way but, it doesn't return any php errors or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do some debugging to narrow down where the problem is occurring. I would start by inspecting the Ajax request in Firebug. Open firebug, click on NET and then XHR. Now run the request in your browser. Does it trigger any HTTP error codes? What params are sent? What is the response? You can also debug on the PHP side using the error_log() function. For example, comment out echo json_encode($view); and try this instead:

```
$response = json_encode($view);
error_log(print_r($response, true));
```

That will log the contents of the JSON object to your PHP error log as a string without interrupting the normal flow of the program.

When you get it working I would use return instead of echo.

Comment: That let me find me debug pretty quick. It's still not working but i've narrowed it down to the php, maybe an issue with how im not binding the results. Thank you!